# How can I drag and drop like browser tabs in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Can someone tell me the name of this effect that is used in browser tabs?

I made the tabs like a browser using HTML, CSS and Javascript, but I wanted to drag between the tabs but the only thing I could do was drag and drop, without that visual effect of it going to the side.

Comment: Please see [ask]. You're expected to make an attempt and show your code.

Comment: Drag and Drop API? ([source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_Drag_and_Drop_API)) ([codepen](https://codepen.io/PJCHENder/pen/VzBVoV/))

Comment: @Jody Exactly, I've already done that, but it's still not as a tab where the tab is being dragged to the sides instead of being ghosted on the mouse pointer

Answer (score -2):

Please refer to [this page](https://web.dev/drag-and-drop/) to get more explanation. I give you an simple example how to do it because you did'nt describe about your HTML.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
  function handleDragStart(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '0.4';

    dragSrcEl = this;

    e.dataTransfer.effectAllowed = 'move';
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/html', this.innerHTML);
    e.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', this.id);
  }

  function handleDragEnd(e) {
    this.style.opacity = '1';

    items.forEach(function (item) {
      item.classList.remove('over');
    });
  }

  function handleDragOver(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }

  function handleDragEnter(e) {
    this.classList.add('over');
  }

  function handleDragLeave(e) {
    this.classList.remove('over');
  }
  
  function handleDrop(e) {
    e.stopPropagation();

    if (dragSrcEl !== this) {
      dragSrcEl.innerHTML = this.innerHTML;
      dragSrcEl.id = this.id;
      this.innerHTML = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/html');
      this.id = e.dataTransfer.getData('text/plain');
    }

    return false;
  }

  let items = document.querySelectorAll('.container .box');
  items.forEach(function(item) {
    item.addEventListener('dragstart', handleDragStart);
    item.addEventListener('dragover', handleDragOver);
    item.addEventListener('dragenter', handleDragEnter);
    item.addEventListener('dragleave', handleDragLeave);
    item.addEventListener('dragend', handleDragEnd);
    item.addEventListener('drop', handleDrop);
  });
  
  let pages = [...document.getElementsByClassName('box')];
  
  $('.box').click(function(e) {
    let id = this.id;
    $('.page').hide();
    $(`#${id}-page`).show();
  });
});
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(5, 1fr);
}

.box {
  border: 3px solid #666;
  background-color: #ddd;
  border-radius: .5em;
  padding: 10px;
  cursor: move;
}

.box:hover {
  background-color: #00BFFF;
}

.box.over {
  border: 3px dotted #666;
}

.page {
  width: 400px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div id="A" draggable="true" class="box">A (Drag Me)</div>
  <div id="B" draggable="true" class="box">B (Drag Me)</div>
  <div id="C" draggable="true" class="box">C (Drag Me)</div>
</div>
<div id="A-page" class="page">
  Hello, A
</div>
<div id="B-page" class="page" style="display: none;">
  Hello, B
</div>
<div id="C-page"  class="page" style="display: none;">
  Hello, C
</div>
```

Comment: I cannot drag your boxes. I can only "select" them (and it shows "Hello, A", "Hello, B" or "Hello, C" depending on the "selected" box). Does it matter I use a smartphone?

Comment: No, just drag it on the computer browser only. For example Drag Box A to Box B. Drag Box B to Box C, etc.

Comment: @Jordy Thanks for your attention but it's not what I need, enter your browser on the desktop and drag the tabs to change their position, that's what I'm talking about

Comment: So it just only browser? Not HTML? My Latest browser can do that, just update to the latest version

Comment: @Jordy When you drag the tabs it goes sideways, that's what I need, if you know how to do it, it would help me a lot.